# Tomcat не компилирует класс для JSP

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <br>
    <%
        for(String name: DatabaseFacade.getBooks()){
            out.println(name + "<br/>");
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Когда класс лежит в default package, получаю:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [13] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]
DatabaseFacade cannot be resolved

```
10:     <h1>Hello World</h1>
11:     <br>
12:     <%
13:         for(String name: DatabaseFacade.getBooks()){
14:             out.println(name + "<br/>");
15:         }
16:     %>
```

Если переложить в пакет с именем (например, test), то волшебным образом начинает ругаться якобы отсутствие драйвера:

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgersql://localhost:5432/postgres

Соответственно, импорт пакета в начале добавляю:

```
<%@ page import="test.DatabaseFacade" %>
```

База стоит 10-я версия, пинг в норме, вручную все запросы проходят. Tomcat 9, JRE 8.
JAR с драйвером базы клал в разные папки (как часто советовали другим) - тоже самое всё...

Код класса на всякий случай:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseFacade {

    public static List<String> getBooks(){
    
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    
        try(Connection connection = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgersql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres", "2309")){
        
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM books.books");
            while(resultset.next()){
                result.add(resultset.getString("name"));
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }   
}
```

UPD: запускаю в Eclipse на Win7; пробовал Томсат 8.5 вместо 9 - всё тоже самое; замена JRE на JDK в настройках проекта также не помогла. Что интересно, на более старом ПО (Eclipse Neon + Java 8 + WinXP/SP3 + Tomcat 7 + PostgreSQL 9.4) абсолютно аналогичные проблемы.

Comment: "JAR с драйвером базы клал в разные папки" - какие папки?

Comment: добавлял через настройки проекта в Web App Libraries, Refrenced Libraries; ещё советовали вручную положить в WebContent/WEB-INF/lib - не помогло, увы.

Comment: какой файл добавлял?

Comment: postgresql-42.2.18.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге вся эта хрень заработала только после того, как класс был переписан "древним" способом, без автозакрытия ресурсов в блоке **try** (и это при использовании Java-8 и Tomcat-9 Карл!!!)

```
public class DatabaseFacade {

public static List<String> getBooks(){
    
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultset = null;
    
    try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection
                ("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres", "2309");
        
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM books.books");
        while(resultset.next()){
            result.add(resultset.getString("name"));
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
       try {
          if(resultset!=null) resultset.close();
       } catch (SQLException se) {
          se.printStackTrace();
       }
       try {
          if(statement!=null) statement.close();
       } catch (SQLException se) {
          se.printStackTrace();
       }
       try {
          if(connection!=null) connection.close();
       } catch (SQLException se) {
          se.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    
    return result;
    }

}
```

литературно выражаясь: "Просто нет слов!"